# Python - Turtle - Get numeric representation (rgb values, hex string) instead of color name as string from Turtle graphics

Tags: python, colors, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am using the [`turtle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) module in python and I want to obtain a numeric representation (RGB, Hex, etc.) of the color instead of the name as a string.

```
from turtle import Screen
print(Screen().bgcolor())
```

The example above prints `>>> white` and I need to get a value like `>>> #FFFFFF` or `>>> rbg(255, 255, 255)` instead.

I am looking for creating complementary colors for arbitrary values so the color name is not useful enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a situation where we need to poke under the hood and access tkinter upon which turtle sits:

```
from turtle import Screen

screen = Screen()
canvas = screen.getcanvas()
root = canvas.winfo_toplevel()

r, g, b = root.winfo_rgb(screen.bgcolor())

print(r, g, b)
```

OUTPUT

```
% python3 test.py
65535 65535 65535
%
```

To pass these values back into turtle, we'll either need to (floating point) divide them by 65535 if we're using the default turtle color model, or shift them by 8 bits for the alternative `colormode(255)`.